# Uploading a PDF file to a CKAN Dataset as a resource fails with "{file} is not json serializable"

Tags: api, python-requests, ckan

My simple python script to create a dataset and to that dataset add a single PDF file as a resource is failing with "{file} is not json serializable".

```html
# coding=utf-8
# import base64
import ckanapi
import requests
import csv
import json
import pprint
import socket
import netifaces as ni

# UPDATE THESE AND ONLY THESE.
api_token = '***'
the_hostname = socket.gethostname()
the_ipaddress = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
site_url = 'http://' + the_ipaddress + ':5000'

endpoint_p = '{}/api/3/action/package_create'.format(site_url)
endpoint_r = '{}/api/3/action/resource_create'.format(site_url)
headers = {'Authorization': api_token}

payload_p = {
    "name": "test01",
    "private": "true",
    "state": "active",
    "owner_org": "b15a6f45-e2ed-4587-8c5e-a92dbc9f157d",
    "maintainer" : "Forms Management",
    "maintainer_email" : "forms.management@province.ca",
    "author" : "Test Author",
    "author_email" : "hughj@province.ca"
}

payload_r = {
    "package_id": "null",
    "name": "English - test01 - Test Description",
    "url": "upload",
    "upload": open('/var/www/upload/2nd/unzipped/002-33-5098E/33-5098E.pdf', 'r'),
    "description": "This is a test resource attached to dataset test01",
    "notes": "This is a longer block of text that is for the resource test01e which is attached to the dataset test01"
}
      
filepaths = {
    "thepath": "/var/www/upload/2nd/unzipped/002-33-5098E/33-5098E.pdf"
}
        
req_p = requests.post(endpoint_p, json=payload_p, headers=headers)

theLastResponse = req_p.json()

theLastPackageCreated = theLastResponse['result']['id']

payload_r["package_id"] = theLastPackageCreated

req_r = requests.post(endpoint_r, json = payload_r, headers = headers) # resource_create()
```

This throws an error "{file} is not json serializable". The file is a PDF, which is a binary file, but I'm not sure if some type of encoding is required (note the commented out "base64" module... I didn't want to go down that road without asking if that's the right approach.)

The CKAN API documentation here:
https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/api/#ckan.logic.action.create.resource_create

says that the "upload" should be a "(FieldStorage (optional) needs multipart/form-data) – (optional)" but all the example scripts I've seen to upload files to CKAN show the code only and exactly what I've done here, no extra pre-processing of the file being uploaded or what not, so I'm not sure exactly what might be the issue... please help if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and ran a modified version against a local dev copy of CKAN and had it work without issue AFTER my mods which are included below.

Most notably:

- payload_r -> All that extra stuff isn't needed but you can include other resource metadata such as description, name, etc if desired just
- req_r -> 1) pass the payload here as `data` instead of `json` as it's `multipart-form-data`. 2) send the file here with the `files` param.

Docs: https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/filestore.html#filestore-api

IMO this is less of a CKAN issue and more of an understanding of the library chosen (i.e. requests). there are many ways to do this with different tools.

I also had to update the payloads to align with my schema but assuming that's correct for yours this should work.

```
# coding=utf-8
# import base64
import ckanapi
import requests
import csv
import json
import pprint
import socket
import netifaces as ni

# UPDATE THESE AND ONLY THESE.
api_token = '***'
the_hostname = socket.gethostname()
the_ipaddress = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
site_url = 'http://' + the_ipaddress + ':5000'

endpoint_p = '{}/api/3/action/package_create'.format(site_url)
endpoint_r = '{}/api/3/action/resource_create'.format(site_url)
headers = {'Authorization': api_token}

payload_p = {
    "name": "test01",
    "private": "true",
    "state": "active",
    "owner_org": "b15a6f45-e2ed-4587-8c5e-a92dbc9f157d",
    "maintainer" : "Forms Management",
    "maintainer_email" : "forms.management@province.ca",
    "author" : "Test Author",
    "author_email" : "hughj@province.ca"
}

payload_r = {
    "package_id": "null"
}
      
filepaths = {
    "thepath": "/var/www/upload/2nd/unzipped/002-33-5098E/33-5098E.pdf"
}
        
req_p = requests.post(endpoint_p, json=payload_p, headers=headers)

theLastResponse = req_p.json()

theLastPackageCreated = theLastResponse['result']['id']

payload_r["package_id"] = theLastPackageCreated

req_r = requests.post(endpoint_r, data=payload_r, headers=headers, files=[('upload', file('/var/www/upload/2nd/unzipped/002-33-5098E/33-5098E.pdf'))]) # resource_create()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this fixed it. Now I can reintegrate the bits that read the metadata and file paths from a .CSV. You made my day!